# Re assign a list efficiently

Tags: python, performance, list

This is a `MWE` of the re-arrainging I need to do:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
b = [[], [], []]

for item in a:
    b[0].append(item[0])    
    b[1].append(item[1])
    b[2].append(item[2])
```

which makes `b` lool like this:

```
b = [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

I.e., every first item in every list inside `a` will be stored in the first list in `b` and the same for lists two and three in `b`.

I need to apply this to a somewhat big `a` list, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a *much* better way to transpose your rows and columns:

```
b = zip(*a)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11), (3, 6, 9, 12)]
```

`zip()` takes multiple sequences as arguments and pairs up elements from each to form new lists. By passing in `a` with the `*` splat argument, we ask Python to expand `a` into separate arguments to `zip()`.

Note that the output gives you a list of tuples; map elements back to lists as needed:

```
b = map(list, zip(*a))
```

Comment: Simple, short, elegant... in one word, Python :)

Comment: I'm amazed. I see that I need to learn quite a bit more of these `python` little gems, I frequently see myself using a `fortran` brute force approach (like in my example above) Thank you very much.

Comment: Impressive:  A nice answer badge in < 15 minutes.